# Get value from ${xxx} into actionlink

Tags: c#, jquery, json, kendo-ui

In this project one of our programmers have written this code.

```
.
.
.
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
         schema: {
             data: "Data",
             total: "Total"
         },
         transport: {
             read: {
                 url: '@Url.Action("List", "Customer")',
                 dataType: "json",
                 type: "POST"
             }
         },
         pageSize: 10,
         serverPaging: true,
         serverFiltering: true,
         serverSorting: true
     });
     $("#listView").kendoListView({
         dataSource: dataSource,
         pageable: true,
         template: kendo.template($("#customerTemplate").html())
     });
     $(".pager").kendoPager({
         dataSource: dataSource
     });
 });
```

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="customerTemplate">
<article>
    **<h3>${CustomerNumber} <a href="Customer/Details/${CustomerNumber}">${FullName}</a></h3>
    ***<h3>${CustomerNumber} @Html.ActionLink(${CustomerNumber}, "Details", "Customer", new {id=${CustomerNumber}}, null)</h3>
    <div class="details">
        <span class="phone" itemprop="telephone"><a href="tel:${Phone}">${Phone}</a></span>
        <span class="email">${Email}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</article>
```

If you take a look at where the two stars are, that's the original code.
My task right now is to translate that code somewhow into a working code as the one where the three stars are. But, no matter how I try, I can't get the values from jquery thing (${CustomerNumber}, ${FullName}) and into the actionlink.
I can barely understand this (newbie, only three months with MVC), so please try and keep it simple for me if you can.

I actually tried to put this code where the article tag is and the call it as @fullname to no avail.

```
@string fullname = ${FullName}
```

I have tried to search SO and Google, but to be honest, I do not even know how to pose the question. Is this related to jquery or kendo? Is it even possible to achieve what I want?
Regards, S

Comment: I have never used Kendo UI but from looking at your code, I doubt this is going to work. Bare in mind razor code is run *server* side when the page loads, you are attempting to render some razor code *after* the page has loaded. Why not stick with how it as at the moment?

Comment: Hi James. The translation is because of trouble with paths. We are currently adding a new customer and some paths got broken, I believe (404 not found etc). Our current path is this (http)://xxxx/customer/Details/1000019  <---number is a customers number. What we need for a functional page is this path (http)://xxxx/newcustomername/Customer/Details/100019   Regards, S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor code is rendered *server* side therefore once the page is loaded any new razor code pulled via JavaScript won't render correctly.

There are ways around this though, one option would be to pull the template from the server so you could pre-render the view before it comes down and then let Kendo do it's mapping.

However, if you want to keep it all client-side, you could have a JS helper method which renders during the page load, in which you can run the razor code e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        function getCustomerUrl(linkText, customerNumber) {
            var urlTemplate = '@Html.ActionLink("linkText", "Details", "Customer", new { id="customerNumber" }, null)';
            return urlTemplate.replace('linkText', linkText).replace('customerNumber', customerNumber);
        }

        ...
    });
</script>
```

Then in your template simply call that method with the relevant parameters i.e.

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="customerTemplate">
<article>
    <h3>#= getCustomerUrl(FullName, CustomerNumber) #</h3>
    <div class="details">
        <span class="phone" itemprop="telephone"><a href="tel:${Phone}">${Phone}</a></span>
        <span class="email">${Email}</span>
    </div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity did you test this? I would think that because the helper method is still javascript its just going to return @Html.ActionLink('1234', "Details", "Customer", new {id='1234'}, null) where 1234 is the customer number.

Comment: @Jared no I haven't tested this, in fact, I have never even used Kendo UI. No that isn't the case here, the JS is rendered with the page therefore any razor will be run server-side.

Comment: but on the server we don't know what customerNumber as that doesn't get processed until we hit the client, so the ActionLink helper doesn't know what to insert.

Comment: @James, I am not sure I understand where your function is supposed to go. I tried to put it before the var datasource ... with the result that the list did not render. All the data was there but no render. Putting the code after the var datasource chunk of code made a list that render, but the customernumber is still not the there, only the text. The path looks like this /customer/Details/' +customerNumber+ '.

Comment: @user2055938 the function just goes where I have specified, in the jQuery ready callback. See update to `getCustomerUrl`. You need to just render the URL as expected first *then* replace the parameter. @Jared yeah you were right, the first example was treating the `' + customerNumber + '` part as a string rather than a variable reference (which makes sense now that I think about it - the update should get around this though.

Comment: Yes, this did work. Thank you very much. I am going to experiment a little bit to see if I can't get, according to requirement, the name of the customer as the linktext instead of param. Hopefully I can ask you again for assistance if I get stuck. For now, thank you both a thousand times, James and @Jared, for your time helping me with this matter. Really appreciated. Regards, S.

Answer (score 0):

The short of it is you cannot do what you want to do. One thing to keep in mind is that all the code that is written in the view is processed on the server.

You are using javascript which gets processed on the client. The reason its not showing is your template has no idea what `@Html.ActionLink(${CustomerNumber}, "Details", "Customer", new {id=${CustomerNumber}}, null)` is. So you have a bit of a mismatch.

The question I would pose is, if this is working why do you need to change it?

**Update base on comments**

I would suggest this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

    var url = @Html.Action("Details", "Customer");

    ...
});
```

Then in your template this

```
<h3>${CustomerNumber} <a href="url + '/' + ${CustomerNumber}">${FullName}</a></h3>
```

Comment: Hi Jared. The translation is because of trouble with paths. We are currently adding a new customer and some paths got broken, I believe (404 not found etc). Our current path is this (http)://xxxx/customer/Details/1000019 <---number is a customers number. What we need for a functional page is this path (http)://xxxx/newcustomername/Customer/Details/100019 I think I am goint to try James solution and see if I can get it to work. Regards, S

Comment: @user2055938 is the new path always going to be (http)://xxxx/newcustomername/Customer/Details/100019

Comment: Yes. AFAIK, all our future customers will have this as their path.

Comment: @user2055938 and old customers will have the old one?

Comment: yes. Your assupmtion is correct. Up until the next major upgrade in hardware for our old customers.